# Generic type that only replaces the methods on an interface with another type leaving the rest unchanged?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a generic type that I expect as being an interface, type literal or a class.

I want the resulting type to have its properties remain the original type and the methods to be `jest.Mock`

```js
type MockedType<T> = /* TODO */  Record<keyof T, jest.Mock>

interface Foobar {
  foo: string
  bar(): void
}

declare const foobar: MockedType<Foobar>

foobar.foo // string
foobar.bar // jest.Mock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this could do the trick:

```
// instead of jest.Mock , just for testing
type Mock = { mock: true }

type Mocked<T extends Object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Function ? Mock : T[K]
}
```

here is an example in [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsg9gYwNZQLxQN5QLaKQLimACcBXaAXwCgrRJY8IATAHgBUoIAPYCAOyYBnKAHkARgCsICYAD40mKlCgBtANJQAlnyhIIIOADMobALqE2605x78hUAGKk+MzXB0B+BsigWrValpwaABBBQwlKC5CQRJtAHMAGkjDQgAKAEo0eVjiBICaOmh4ZGYw9BK9VhDZIA)